# What to use Material-UI or Semantic UI in React App

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, semantic-ui

Which is the best one to use and if possible, please provide the difference(s) and pros/cons of these two.

Material-UI vs Semantic UI I am trying to build my UI and really confused as what to use.

I need nice look and feel, Responsive layout and more modern look in React APP, also with good documentation.

Please suggest me the best one and if possible with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantic ui all the way!

If you plan on customizing one of these libraries then don't go with material UI. It's very opinionated and not meant to be that overwritten with the exception of colors. Semantic ui however is meant to be fully customized. Look at their theming.

As others have said, Material is very opinionated but good if that's what you're looking for. The Javascript and React portion of semantic is pretty solid and allows you to pick what you need. The CSS of semantic still takes some work but most UI frameworks do